# How to access action controller value from jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I m new ti jquery. Anybody tell me How to access action controller's value from jquery

I have following code in view...

```
<% @user_rep.each do |result| %>
<%= link_to result.time,{:action =>'download_log'}, :id => 'l123'%></td>
<% end %>
```

And I jave written following code in jquery...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#l123").click(function() {
    jQuery("#file").show("slow");     // Showing some div 
    ####What to write here
   });
});
```

And i coded in download_log action

```
def download_log
IO.foreach "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/#{filename}" do |line|
                    @file_content << line
                    @file_content << '<br/>'
            end
end
```

Any body tell me.. When i click on 'l123' then a div will be shown n the controller action "download_log" is automatically called? If it is possible then how can i access download_log's  value "@file_content" in jquery. Please help me.

Comment: If you want the controller action to be done as soon as you have clicked , and you want that to be done in the jQuery you have to use jQuery-ajax.

Comment: if my answer solved your issue please mark it as the answer, if not provide more details in your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#l123").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlOfControllerAndAction,
            type: "get",
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#file").html(response);
                $("#file").show("slow")
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },
            // callback handler that will be called on completion
            // which means, either on success or error
            complete: function () {
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Ajax jQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/